# Passing thread names as gloabl variables to a function

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I'm a bit stuck, i'm trying to pass thread names given by the system to my function so that i can print the start and end time of the current thread working in the function, i'm using global variables name for that. The user has to input a number in the given interval. The thread names work fine when i inputed 1001 but if i input numbers like 1200 or 10001 the names do not fit anymore. I put examples of the output, output 1 is not what i'm looking, output 2 is what i need. I'm not sure what is causing the name change. If any additional information is needed i'm happy to provide it

```
import os
from posixpath import abspath
import time
import sys
import signal
import threading
import platform
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
import math
```

```
lokot = threading.Lock()
lista = []
name = 0
name3 = 0
def divisor(start,end):
    lokot.acquire()
    start = time.time()
    print('{} started working at {}'.format(name, start))
    for i in range(int(start),int(end)+1):
        if int(end) % i == 0:
            lista.append(i)
    end = time.time()
    print('{} ended working at {}'.format(name, end))
    lokot.release()
def new_lista():
    lokot.acquire()
    start = time.time()
    nlista = []
    for i in lista:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            nlista.append(i)
    print(nlista)
    print('{} was executed in time frame {}'.format(name3,time.time()-start))
    lokot.release()

def f4():
    while (True):
        print ('Input a non negative number in given range <1000,200000>')
        number = input()
        if number.isalpha() or not number or int(number) not in range(1000,200000) :
            print('Number entered is not in the interval <1000,200000>')
            continue
        else:
            global name
            global name3
            x = int(number) / 2
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=divisor, args=(1, x))
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=divisor, args=(1, number))
            t3 = threading.Thread(target=nova_lista)
            name = t1.name
            t1.start()
            name = t2.name
            t2.start()
            name3 = t3.name
            t3.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
            t3.join()
            break
```

```
Input 1:
100001
Output 1:
Thread-1 started working at 1624538800.4813018
Thread-2 ended working at 1624538800.4887686
Thread-2 started working at 1624538800.4892647
Thread-2 ended working at 1624538800.5076165
[2, 4, 8, 10, 16, 20, 40, 50, 80, 100, 200, 250, 400, 500, 1000, 1250, 2000, 2500, 5000, 6250, 10000, 12500, 25000, 50000]
Thread-3 dwas executed in time frame 0.0
```

```
Input 2:
1001
Output 2:
Thread-1 started working at 1624538882.90607
Thread-1 ended working at 1624538882.9070616
Thread-2 started working at 1624538882.9074266
Thread-2 ended working at 1624538882.9089162
[2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40, 50, 100, 200, 250, 500, 1000, 1250, 2500, 5000]
Thread-3 dretva se izvodila 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't necessarily work:

```
name = t1.name
t1.start()
name = t2.name
```

Nothing prevents the second assignment from happening before the `t1` thread accesses the `name` variable.

Q: Why don't you just assign names when you create the threads instead of letting the `Threading` library assign them? E.g.;

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=divisor, args=(1, x), name="t1")
```

Comment: Tbh i'm doing this for an assignment, I already tought about doing it your way. But the requirment is to use system assigned names.

Comment: @SebastianMiklosevic, Ok, then why have the global `name` variable at all? Why not let each thread ask for its own name? `threading.current_thread().name`

Comment: Oh didn't think this one up, i was focused on the idea that i need to somehow pass the thread name in my mind only accessible in the function where the thread is started. I bit of tunnel vision here.